# java flex GUI compatibility for desktop application

Tags: java, apache-flex

i want to know if it is possible to create GUI for java desktop based application in Adobe FLEX.

or any other powerful framework to make rich GUI interfaces for Java desktop applications.

Please share your valuable views on this.

Comment: No you can't. Use JavaFX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to know if it is possible to create GUI for java desktop based
>   application in Adobe FLEX.

Yes, no and sort of.  Flex is primarily used in client server applications.  If you have a java server that exposes functionality via web services there is no reason you can't write a Flex GUI on top of that.  And there is no reason that GUI can't target a browser (with Flash Player) or the desktop (with AIR).

There is also no reason that the client and the server cannot be the same machine.  It will however present a significant installation challenge in deploying this application.  I'm not sure if these challenges outweigh any benefits that Flex may bring to the table.

Ignoring the client/server nature of Flash/AIR, you can use Native Extensions or NativeProcess to include and execute Java Code as part of an AIR application.  This is probably the approach I would take if I really wanted to use Flex and Java together in a desktop application.

Comment: thanks it solved my query but i can't make my application based on client server achitecture it will increse my work for maintenance which is not acceptable in my case.

Comment: Then NativeExtension / NativeProcess is your best bet.  Or using a technology other than Flex.